# Moving Magento from subdirectory to root causes 'failed to open stream' errors

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, migration, move

I've just gone through the process of moving a dev instance of Magento from a /dev dir into the root dir but it's still looking for files in the /dev dir.

I've updated the web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url values, cleared /var/cache and /var/session double checked the .htaccess RewriteBase, removed the /community and /local directories (as a test), updated all my folders and files to the correct permissions, I'm not sure what else to try. I've hit a wall.

I've made this kind of move several times without issue, but for some reason this value is "stuck" somewhere and I can't figure out where.

The error_log contains this (it should **not** have the /dev dir in the file path):

> PHP Warning: include_once(Mage/Core/functions.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in /httpdocs/dev/app/Mage.php on
>   line 49
>
> PHP Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Mage/Core/functions.php'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='/httpdocs/dev/app/code/local:/httpdocs/dev/app/code/community:/httpdocs/dev/app/code/core:/httpdocs/dev/lib:.:')
>   in /httpdocs/dev/app/Mage.php on line 49
>
> PHP Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in /httpdocs/dev/app/Mage.php on line 50
>
> PHP Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for
>   inclusion
>   (include_path='/httpdocs/dev/app/code/local:/httpdocs/dev/app/code/community:/httpdocs/dev/app/code/core:/httpdocs/dev/lib:.:')
>   in /httpdocs/dev/app/Mage.php on line 50
>
> PHP Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in
>   /httpdocs/dev/app/Mage.php on line 53

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Just trying to find tips on where else to look. Thank you!

Magento version 1.7.0.2

Comment: If you drop a var_dump(__FILE__); at the top of your `index.php` file, what file path shows up?

Comment: This returns

string(4) "FILE"

Comment: I believe Alan actually wanted you to use `__FILE__`, but was caught by Stackoverflow formatting.

Comment: Oops!  **shakes fist at markdown**  What happens when you drop a var_dump(\_\_FILE\_\_) at the top of your `index.php` file?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, the __FILE__ was pointing to the correct file, turns out a server reboot fixed the issue. So weird. And also so frustrating to spend that much time on something simple! Isn't that always the way.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `include_path=...` parameter in your php.ini file to NOT include dev` folder. BTW, next time please mention (tags) which version of Magento you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Who is your host? If you can - try ending your php processes (or reboot). Looks like your application is in memory and still thinks it is in the dev dir.

Comment: Which worked because on boot it cleared the system `/tmp` folder where Magento stored its cache. Your real problem is that you have incorrect ownership and permissions on your Magento files and folders, especially on your `var/` folder and contents. Your problem still exists. **nothing** was stuck in memory, it was stuck in cache files in the system `/tmp`